# Filter columns in a dataframe using a specific word

Tags: r, string, dplyr

I have a data frame that contains 70 columns, most of them are numeric variables collecting gender data. I'd like to subset the data frame so I only have male numeric variables and female numeric variables. The goal is to get the total sum of both male and female counts in the dataframe.

Hypothetically the DF looks like this

```
Client <- c("A", "B", "C","D","B","D","C")
ContactPerson <- c("Andrew","Mary","John","Barbara","Mary","Barbara","John")
`Rural Male persons` <- c(3, 1, 3, 4, 5, 3, 1)
`Rural female persons` <- c(3, 5, 3, 2, 6,2,1)
`Urban Male persons` <- c(4, 2, 5, 1, 0, 4, 2)
`Urban female persons` <- c(6, 9, 1, 7, 3, 2, 1)

DF <- data.frame(Client, ContactPerson, `Rural Male persons`, `Rural female persons`, `Urban Male persons`, `Urban female persons`)
```

I've tried subsetting to get **Male** only numeric variables using these functions

```
 Male <- DF %>%
      select(matches("Male|Client|ContactPerson"))
```

and

```
Male <- DF %>%
  select(contains(c("Partner", "Person", "Male")))
```

But it still brings both Male and female variables. I guess the reason for this is because of presence of the word Male in Female. Is there a way to explicitly subset these columns using a specific word. e.g. **Male**?

Comment: In this case I think you can just take the argument `ignore_case` and set it to false. Or use `DF |> 
  select(matches("\\.Male|Client|ContactPerson"))`

Comment: If you want to assign the column names with spaces, add `check.names = FALSE` when creating the dataframe.

Comment: @DarrenTsai, thanks for the tip when creating the data frame

Comment: @JustJames, this is the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do this with `grep`.

For example like this:

```
Client <- c("A", "B", "C","D","B","D","C")
ContactPerson <- c("Andrew","Mary","John","Barbara","Mary","Barbara","John")
`Rural Male persons` <- c(3, 1, 3, 4, 5, 3, 1)
`Rural female persons` <- c(3, 5, 3, 2, 6,2,1)
`Urban Male persons` <- c(4, 2, 5, 1, 0, 4, 2)
`Urban female persons` <- c(6, 9, 1, 7, 3, 2, 1)

DF <- data.frame(Client, ContactPerson, `Rural Male persons`, `Rural female persons`, `Urban Male persons`, `Urban female persons`)

col_names <- colnames(DF)
male_cols <- grep('\\bMale\\b', col_names, value = T)

Male <- DF %>%
  select(male_cols)
```